# Cant select Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-developer-api, android-studio-arctic-fox

I just upgraded from Android Studio to Android Studio Arctic Fox and while creating project i only see one option for Kotlin there is no option for java please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

In New Project Wizard if you choose **Empty Compose Activity** then it will show only Kotlin. So make sure to choose any other activity e.g. **Empty Activity**.
If this is not the case then try closing and restarting Android Studio.

Update: In the newer **Android Studio** version **Empty Activity** is **Empty Compose Activity** and **Empty Views Activity** is with that activity with xml UI.

Comment: Any ideas as to why they disabled Java for this particular template?

Answer (score 2):

Try this quick solution
go to file > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button.

after try again
Select either Java or Kotlin from the Language check this drop-down menu

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project, you cannot change the language if you select **Empty Activity**. So, choose another activity. Then you can select java.

Comment: Did anyone find out why they decided to make this change at all?